# How to stop html button redirecting to another web page automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML button:

```
<button>
   <img id = "click-me" src="https:..." alt="Add to List" style="width: 50px"/>
</button>
```

Which, when clicked, should execute this JQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#click-me").click(function () {
        document.getElementById('list').style.backgroundColor = "red";      
    });
});
```

But, instead of doing what I want it to do, clicking the button sends me to another page of my website. How do I stop this? Thanks

EDIT:

here is the full html of the page:

```
<div class="form">
      <h1>Create A Meeting</h1>

      <%= form_for(@newevent) do |f| %>

          <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Title" %>
          <!--< f.collection_select :location, Location.all, :id, :locName %> FOR WHEN LOCATIONS ARE A THING-->
          <%= f.text_field :description, :placeholder => "Short Description" %>

          <div>
            <h2>Who's involved?</h2>
            <p>select a colleague to compare their calendar with yours</p>
            <%= f.collection_select :id,
                                    Customer.where(business_id: current_customer.business_id),
                                    :id,
                                    :full_name,
                                    { prompt: 'Select' },
                                    { id: "colleage-select", onChange: "renderColCal(this)" } %>
            <button id="click-me" type="button">
              <img  src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements/700/07_plus-128.png" alt="Add to Event" style="width: 50px"/>
            </button>



            <div class = 'row'>
                <div class = 'col-md-6' id = 'left-calendar-wrapper'>
                  <h3>Your calendar:</h3>
                  <%= render partial: '/calendars/show', locals: {} %>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6" id="calendar-wrapper">
                  <h3>Your colleague's calendar:</h3>


                </div>
              <div>
                <p>Meeting Participants:</p>
                <ol id ="list">
                  <li>list</li>

                </ol>
              </div>


            </div>


          </div>



          <div>
            <h2>when do you want it to start?</h2>
            <%= f.datetime_select :starts_at, :placeholder => "when do you want it?"   %>
          </div>



          <div>
            <h2>when do you want it to end?</h2>
            <%= f.datetime_select :ends_at, :placeholder => "when should it end?"  %>
          </div>


          <%= f.submit "Create Meeting", class: "btn-submit" %>
      <% end %>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JQuery remains the same

Comment: Add a `return false;` at the end of the click function.

Comment: I have just tried this and it does not stop it redirecting

Comment: @SCraig Try both... `e.preventDefault()` as well.

Comment: @SCraig Add the `id="click-me"` to the `button` and not `img`.

Comment: If you're only using `<button>` for its appearance, you could certainly try just using an `img`, applying a `myButtonClass` class attribute to it, and styling that instead. (EDIT: Or, add `type="button"` to the button so it doesn't submit by default)

Comment: I have put both in my method and yet it is still redirecting.. Could there be something else going on?

Comment: @SCraig Kindly check this: **http://output.jsbin.com/zefonubami**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the `id="click-me"` to the `button` and not `img`. And also, please add `type="button"` for the `button`.

Either add `e.preventDefault()` or `return false`:

```
$(function () {
    $("#click-me").click(function () {
        document.getElementById('list').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        return false;
    });
});
```

Or:

```
$(function () {
    $("#click-me").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('list').style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
});
```

Comment: You can indeed have an `img` tag inside a `button`.  Please edit your answer.

Comment: Otherwise, spot on (:

Comment: @michael Sure... Ha ha.

Comment: this did not fix my problem

Comment: @SCraig Did you add jQuery?

Comment: I just used what you gave me. I have set type="button" in my button tag and it has stopped redirecting, but now it won't execute the function

Comment: Oh ok, I understand what I did wrong it was a typo, thanks

Comment: I have accepted it, but you should update your answer to also suggest adding type="button" to my button tag, as that is what actually fixed the original problem

Answer (score 1):

Button itself wouldn't do anything. I guess it is in form and when clicked it submits form. So You should prevent that:

```
$('#click-me').parents('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or just add `type="button"` to button. If no type is provided button is handled as submit button (`type="submit"`).

```
<button type="button">
   <img id = "click-me" src="https:..." alt="Add to List" style="width: 50px"/>
</button>
```

Paste more of Your HTML/JS, because looking at this code **button shouldn't do anything**

Comment: I will edit my question. The button IS within a form, but I do not want it to submit the form, I just want it to update the visuals of the page.

Comment: just add type to Your button `<button type="button"></button>`